# Timestamp script, not working (pasting/dragging formula, cell value)

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp, google-sheets-formula

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

The current version of the script is working, but the result is shown only when the data is entered manually. I am using onEdit trigger.

1. There is column A, which displays the time and date of the entered information from column B, column B with the product code that refers to column C. If I try to drag the formula through column B to display the data, then the Date and Time in column A are not displayed. How can this be fixed?
2. The first table is on sheet 1, and the data that turned out needs to be duplicated on sheet 2. In this case, I refer to the desired cell in sheet A, but if the data from column B and C are displaying then the date of entry from column A (with timestamp) does not displays.
3. If the data from column B is dragged down, then the script does not react to these changes, and, accordingly, the date of entry is not displayed in column A.

**CODE**

````
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
var idRow = e.range.getRow();
if ( idCol == 2 && sheet.getName() =='FB data' ) {
var Value = e.range.offset(0, -1).getValues();  
if ( Value == "" ) {

var vartoday = getDate();
var varnow = getTime();


 var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+03:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
   var r = e.range;
 
sheet.getRange(idRow, 1).setValue(varnow);
}
}
}

function getTime() {
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate());
//return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'PST', 'yyyy.MM.dd');
return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+03:00', "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}```
````

Comment: Unfortunately it is intended behavior that Apps Script triggers fire only on manual edits - see [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions).

Answer (score 1):

// Dragging in a sheet is a manual edit

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if ( e.range.getColumn() == 2 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'FB data' ) {

    // getValues() returns a 2D Array [[]]
    var Value = e.range.offset(0, -1).getValues()

    // loop through each row replacing empty cell with result of calling getTime function
    for(let i = 0, len = Value.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (Value[i][0] == "") {
        Value[i][0] = getTime()
      }
    }
    // write the mutated values back to the sheet
    e.range.offset(0, -1).setValues(Value)
  }
}

function getTime() {
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate());
//return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'PST', 'yyyy.MM.dd');
return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+03:00', "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```